# Derivative-free optimization of function with a flat region

Tags: optimization

I'm attempting derivative-free minimization of, essentially, a black-box function in one dimension. Up to now I've been using BOBYQA as [implemented in NLopt](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/NLopt_Algorithms#Local_derivative-free_optimization). The shape of the function looks like this:

[image]

Clearly, giving a good initial guess will help immensely here, as I can avoid the nasty flat region to the right of the graph. However, sometimes a **good** initial guess is unavailable, and it can end up in the flat region and hence never find the minima.

- Are there any tips/tricks for getting out/avoiding the flat region at
  all?
- Would a simple Fibonacci / Golden Section search be any better?
- Or would my time be better spent on working out good initial guesses?

Comment: 1) BOBYQA is sensitive to `initstep` / stepsizes $\rho_t$:
"if you rescale the objective function then you are effectively changing the initial rho.
This changes the convergence rate ..." -- S.G.Johnson.

2) try [Py-BOBYQA](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/robertsl/pybobyqa/) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following works in any dimension:

If you have a poor initial guess $x_0$ only (but outside the completely flat region), minimize $f(x)+c_k||x-x_k||^2$ for $k=0$ with some small $c_0$, call the result $x_1$, and iterate with a strongly decreasing sequence of $c_k$'s. In many cases $c_1=0$ will already work.

Comment: Thanks - do you have a link/reference where this is explained in a little more detail?

Comment: @blochwave: No; Isn't it self-explaining? These sort of tricks are at best in little remarks scattered through papers with applications.

Comment: Sure - I do understand it, just curious how much has been written about it. Thanks!

Comment: @ArnoldNeumaier Must admit, I don't get it at all ;)  Firstly, surely a guess _outside_ the completely flat region is a "good initial guess", rendering the method unnecessary?  Secondly, I can't see what the method is doing!  Can you give any hints?

Comment: @m4r35n357: 500 is no longer in the completely flat region, and is not yet a good guess in my usage of the word. The regularization ensures that one doesn't move very far away from $x_k$ but achieves some reduction in $f(x)$. Repetition therefore improves the guesses iteratively.

Comment: @ArnoldNeumaier thanks very much for the reply!  I would say that 500 has enough of a slope on it to find the minimum, but that is just my opinion ;)  However your hint is interesting, so I'll stare at that until I get it!  I have a function like this in mind . . .https://www.sfu.ca/~ssurjano/easom.html

Comment: @m4r35n357: 1000 is flat on the graph but probably still not completely flat numerically, and the regularization with a small but not too small value of $c$ will move it to near 500!

Comment: @ArnoldNeumaier are you saying that you make the flat bit "non-flat", then solve, then make it slightly less "non-flat, solve again,  & so on?  If not, then I have failed to understand!  I am still trying to work out if this is a technique that can I can make use of myself.

Comment: Yes. The point of the regularization is just to ensure that when you start at a nearly flat point, your root finder (e.g., Newton's method) will not overshoot and attempt to try a very negative value next. As long as there is a numerically perceptible slope, there will be progress.

Answer (score 4):

In your particular case, you could consider transforming the $x$ variable by replacing the problem by the following: find $y$ so that $f(e^y)$ is minimal. In essence, you're compressing the long tail to the right and thereby make its gradient steeper.

Comment: That is an interesting approach, I guess whether it works depends on "how flat" the flat part is.  I have a feeling that it will fail if the function is "truly flat", as the "expansion" will be flat also . . . ?

Comment: @m4r35n357 As is universally the case, if you know something about the function you're dealing with, put that into the formulation. If you know that your problem has a double-exponential tail, use $x \to e^{(e^y)}$ as your substitution.

Comment: I am frequently puzzled by the level of _a priori_ knowledge needed to solve many optimization problems ;)  Why not just avoid the flat bit altogether if you know it is there?

Comment: @m4r35n357 No, not *necessary*. You can just make algorithms *more efficient* if you know something about the problem. As for your question: "Why not just avoid the flat bit altogether if you know it is there?" If the function you're trying to minimize is given as a function with a number of parameters, and all you're given is a starting point, how do you *tell* that you're in the flat region? How do you *know* that for the given set of parameters, the function even has a flat region?

Comment: That does not answer my question.  I ask in another way, how do you mitigate (whether exponentially or otherwise) for a "troublesome" region that you _don't even know is there_?

Comment: You can't always. That's why it is easy to find minima of some functions, and not easy for others.